# Power Automate Custom Connector Test thinks file output is a string

Tags: swagger-2.0, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

My Web API method returns a binary PDF file in the response body and I've set this in the swagger file in the Custom Connector of Power Automate.  However, despite the output being a binary PDF file AND that the property type is "file", the Test function in the Custom Connector UI still thinks its returning a "string" even through it clearly isn't!

**Question: Any ideas what I'm doing wrong to make the tester think it's a string?**

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[image]
Here is my swagger for the Web API method (take note of the 200 response of `schema: {type: file, format: binary}`:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info: {title: xxxx, version: '1.0', description: xxxx}
host: xxxx.azurewebsites.net
basePath: /api
schemes: [https]
consumes: []
produces: []
paths:
  /FrontPageGenerator:
    post:
      description: xxxx
      operationId: FrontPageGenerator
      summary: FrontPageGenerator
      parameters:
      - name: body
        in: body
        required: true
        schema: {type: string}
      consumes: [application/json]
      produces: [application/json, application/pdf]
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successfully generated composite PDF file
          schema: {type: file, format: binary}
        '400':
          description: Invalid input
          schema: {$ref: '#/definitions/GenericJson'}
          examples:
            application/json: {message: No body}
        '406':
          description: Not Acceptable Accept Type
          schema: {$ref: '#/definitions/BasicError'}
          examples:
            application/json: {message: Not Acceptable}
definitions:
  BasicError:
    type: object
    properties:
      message: {type: string}
  GenericJson: {type: object}
```